# Argument Dependent Look (ADL) considering template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, argument-dependent-lookup

I have a couple of namespaces, each with a function template named `f`.

```
// f() and Widget
namespace A {
  struct Widget { };

  template <typename T>
  void func(const T&) { }
}

// f() and caller()
namespace B {
  template <typename T>
  void func(const T&) { }

  template <typename T>
  void caller(const T& t) {
    func(t); // error occurs here
  }
}

template <typename T>
class Wrap { };

int main() {
  Wrap<A::Widget> w{};
  B::caller(w); // triggers error
}
```

The above produces the following error

```
error: call of overloaded ‘func(const Wrap<A::Widget>&)’ is ambiguous
     func(t);
     ~~~~^~~
note: candidate: void B::func(const T&) [with T = Wrap<A::Widget>]
   void func(const T&) { }
        ^~~~
note: candidate: void A::func(const T&) [with T = Wrap<A::Widget>]
   void func(const T&) { }
        ^~~~
```

Why is `A::func` considered if `Wrap` is in the global namespace? Shouldn't `B::caller` call `B::func`?

Answer (score 2):

ADL doesn't just considered the arguments to the function in the case of a template. Here you have `Wrap<A::Widget>` as the argument to `B::caller`. Because `caller` is in `namespace B`, `B::func` is obviously considered. The reason for `A::func` being considered comes from the below (emphasis added)

> N659 6.4.2/(2.2) [basic.lookup.argdep]
>
> If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is
>   a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the innermost
>   enclosing namespaces of its associated classes. **Furthermore, if T is a class template specialization,
>   its associated namespaces and classes also include: the namespaces and classes associated with the
>   types of the template arguments provided for template type parameters** [...]

Because `A::Widget` is a template argument to `Wrap`, `A` is also an associated namespace of `Wrap<A::Widget>`

This example can be made to compile as expected by preventing ADL by using the qualified name:

```
template <typename T>    
void caller(const T& t) {    
  B::func(t);      
}
```

or by enclosing the function name in paretheses

```
template <typename T>    
void caller(const T& t) {    
  (func)(t);      
}
```